# Python Question: spread out spacing to string, there is a specific width for the string total

Tags: python, for-loop, insert

Need to create a string that spreads out a specific amount of spaces, given a list of words and number of spaces. Say you have 3 spaces to spread out and the list has 3 words, the result should be:
`"(word)space|space(word)space(word)"`

1. string must end with a word
2. Should also be applicable to different amount of spaces and words.
3. from left to right the amount of spaces shouldn't differ by MORE than one space in-between words:

   e.g. `"(word)space|space|space(word)space(word)"` --> wrong (3 spaces, than 1)

   e.g. `"(word)space|space(word)space|space(word)"` --> correct (2 spaces, than 2 spaces)

   e.g. `"(word)space|space(word)space(word)"`       --> correct (2 spaces, than 1)

I've tried for loops but I can't figure out how to jump to a different index and it produces an extra space:

```
word = ['123','45','6']
z = len(word)
spaces = 3

while spaces > 0:
  for i in range(1,z):
    word.insert(i,' ')
    spaces -= 1
    
print(word)
```

output: `['123', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '45', '6']`

Got an extra space and can't jump to correct index to insert space.

Comment: Do you need that to block align text? Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution merge several conjoint spaces in a single string, I don't know if it's what you need :

```
word = ['123', '45', '6', '789']
z = len(word)
count = 0
spaces = 5

# computes the string to be inserted (except the last one) :
sp = round(spaces / (z-1))
space = ' ' * sp    

for i in range(1, z):
    # handle the last space specifically :
    if i == z-1: space =  ' ' * (spaces - count) 
    # the target index grows with insertions :
    word.insert(i * 2 - 1, space)
    # count the number of spaces inserted :
    count += sp


print(word) #==> ['123', '  ', '45', '  ', '6', ' ', '456']
```

EDIT : here is a solution to distribute the spaces evenly with the greatest(s) at the beginning. It uses two loops instead of one :

```
word = ['123', '45', '6', '789', '45', '6', '13']
z = len(word)
spaces = 17

sp      = spaces / (z-1) # spaces / z as a float
spSum   = 0              # sum of integer spaces 
spacing = []             # collector

for i in range(1, z):
    new    = round(sp * i) - spSum # computes the current integer space
    spSum  += new                  # adds it to the sum
    spacing.append(new)            # and collects it

spacing = sorted(spacing, reverse = True) # Sorts the collected spaces in descending order 

for i in range(1, z):              # Finally inserts :
    word.insert(i * 2 - 1, spacing[i-1] * ' ')
```

Here are the produced list of spacings with 4 different cases

```
#z = 7, spaces = 17
print(spacing) #==> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2] # Single smallest at end
#z = 7, spaces = 18
print(spacing) #==> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] # All equal
#z = 7, spaces = 19
print(spacing) #==> [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] # Single greatest at beginning
#z = 7, spaces = 21
print(spacing) #==> [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3] # Other distribution
```

Comment: @dspr-- Is there a way where the number of spaces go from highest to lowest. For example if you had four words and 7 spaces; the output would be:(word|3spaces|word|2paces|word|2paces|word) vs the code you provided (great btw) the output is (word|2spaces|word|2paces|word|3paces|word)

Comment: Thanks dspr. If  'z  = 7' and  'spaces = 13' the last outputted space is 1, the space before the last would have 3 spaces. The total spaces in-between strings can't differ by more than 1 space. In this case they would differ by 2 spaces given that the last has 1 space and the spaces before that have 3. Thank you again!!

Comment: See my edit again, I think it's the good one this time.